# Stitching sub-images in MATLAB to form the final image

Tags: image, matlab

I looked thoroughly in internet to see how to stitch sub-images but none corresponds to my need. So I am in need of an explanation before I understand how the whole programming process might go.

I have taken images of a line with a camera at a fixed distance and varying the camera position along the line with steps of 5mm and taking always an image. I continue until I take the final image of the end of the line.

I have the images stored in Excel as files (35files). I have already converted the files (images) into an array of 2D matrices.

So my question now is:

How do I stitch the images from the first sub-image to the last sub-image in MATLAB to get the final exact image of the line? How do I treat the different sub-images? I do not understand just the basics of stitching! How does the dimensions of the line gets preserved on the final image?

Comment: Can you post a reduced data set? 2 or 3 small matrices.

Comment: Your question is actually too broad. You have to be very specific and make sure that people can replicate your problem. Please update your post with an [mcve](https:/stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user1543042. The matrices I have are very long,so I will give 3 simple matrices,representing images,which I want to stitch. They are: M1=rand(12,30),M2=rand(12,50) and M3=rand(12,70). Let's say I took these images with the camera and moved the camera along the image at steps of 5mm. Will the steps be used in the algorithm?